# how to compare values between 2 columns, if match , output corresponding column

Tags: vlookup

I Have an excel workbook that has 2 tab tab reference & Sheet 3
i want to compare **Column W** from sheet 3 with **Column D** from tab reference
**If they match**, it will output corresponding  **Colomn E** value to **Column AP**.
Otherwise just leave blank

tab reference

```
Colomn D    Colomn E
001         321
002         554
003         789
```

Sheet 3

```
Column W    Column AP
012
002
048
001
```

Desired Result

Sheet 3

```
Column W    Column AP
012
002          554
048
001          321
```

Any idea? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP` and enter the following formula into the `AP` column, row 2 (assuming the first row is row 2):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W2,'tab reference'!$D$2:$E$3,2,FALSE),"")
```

The range `'tab reference'!$D$2:$E$3` refers to the lookup data you showed us.  This assumes you only have three rows to lookup, but you may change this formula if you have more than this.